# App is Crashed when parsing the Xml file in Xamarin IOS Project

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I Converted the IOS Static Library into Dll file. I Included the converted Dll file into my Xamarin IOS Project. In IOS Static Library  I used the NSXmlParser to Parse the Xml file. When I parse the Xml file In Xamarin IOS Project via Dll file, app is crashed. Following Error Message is printed in console

```
  mono-rt:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>

  mono-rt:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) ApiDefinitions.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00025, 0xffffffff>

  mono-rt:   at IOSComponents.FLXSFlexDataGrid.BuildFromXML (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSData) <IL 0x0002d, 0x000cf>

 mono-rt:   at Sample.ExampleViewControllerBase.BuildGridFromXmlResource (IOSComponents.FLXSFlexDataGrid,string) [0x00065] in /Users/Test/Workspace/Solution/Sample/SampleViews/ExampleViewControllerBase.cs:41

 mono-rt:   at IOSComponentsSample.AutoResizingGridViewController.ViewDidLoad () [0x00095] in /Users/Test/Workspace/Solution/Sample/SampleViews/AutoResizingGridViewController.cs:43

 mono-rt:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0004e, 0xffffffff>

 mono-rt:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>

 mono-rt:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <IL 0x000a6, 0xffffffff>

mono-rt:   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:39

mono-rt:   at IOSComponentsSample.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00008] in /Users/Test/Workspace/Solution/Sample/Main.cs:17

mono-rt:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00050, 0xffffffff>

mono-rt: 
Native stacktrace:

mono-rt: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

I did't understand the about the error. Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: This appears to be only a part of the error message, not the whole thing. Either way, ViewDidLoad() is calling BuildGridFromXmlResource() and that is calling FLXSFlexDataGrid.BuildFromXML() and that seems to be throwing an error somewhere in the native part of the Mono RunTime.

Are you sure there's not more information further to the top?

Comment: @Frank, I debugging console it will print above mentioned error messages only.It not printing any other message.. after that app is crashed. is any other way to print all logs?

Comment: This is a native crash, which means that something happened inside your FLXSFlexDataGrid component.   As to what that is, it is hard to tell as the component does not seem to provide this kind of information.